# Landscape printing in Rave Reports Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, report, landscape, rave-reports

I have create report designs in Rave (Delphi 7). However they are in portrait mode. When user selects landscape printing from Print Setup, it is printer in portrait again anyway. How can I fix it, so that Rave generates reports in a format which user selects during print setup?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the documentation "[Rave Reports](http://www.nevrona.com/files/rave5.pdf)" [PDF]

First, by default, the printer settings are used.

Second, you can try to set the SystemPrinter.Orientation property to poLandScape

Also have a look at Anchors:

> Anchors can be used to create
>   adaptable Reports when combined with
>   other Reporting features. Imagine that
>   a Report needs to be defined that can
>   be printed in either landscape or
>   portrait orientation or that the
>   Report may be run on different size
>   papers. Setting the Anchors properly
>   will allow one Report to adjust to
>   these changing conditions.

Comment: Have you done this? I have tried using anchors, but it didn't work correctly. Maybe because BE Rave is a little buggy, but I still couldn't find appropriate solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using "Page Component" in your report, it has a property named "Orientation". Set it to landscape.